# Can iCloud Drive be used on watchOS?

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, icloud-drive

When I try to use FileManager.default.ubiquityIdentityToken on watchOS it always returns nil. This works just fine on iOS and macOS and it is the recommended way to check whether iCloud Drive is available to use. What's going on?

The error on the console offers up the following:

> WatchKit Extension[257:19594] [default] [ERROR] error while getting
>   ubiquityIdentityToken: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The
>   connection to service named com.apple.bird.token was invalidated."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named
>   com.apple.bird.token was invalidated.}

Answer (score 1):

Turns out watchOS does not support iCloud Drive at all, nor does it support the key-value storage iCloud service. CloudKit can be used, however, although care should be taken to use a custom-named container on watchOS that matches the one that is used on iOS so that the apps on each platform can share data from the same container.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1935/_index.html